# Running SFX from Application: Change working directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winrar, sfx

I have an application that starts an SFX (self-extracting executable) file and extracts it.

The input file is located at `c:\sfx\sfx.exe` but it currently extracts to my application's start up folder (`c:\myapp\`,) rather than where it is stored (`c:\sfx\`.)

How can I alter where the output goes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you start an application, the 'working directory' is the directory from which you start it (unless explicitly specified otherwise.) You can change this, however, using [`SetCurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory.aspx) of the [`Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ta62wh3.aspx) class.

An example from the referenced MSDN page:

```
string dir = @"C:\test";        
try
{
    //Set the current directory.
    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dir);
}
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The specified directory does not exist. {0}", e);
}
// Print to console the results.
Console.WriteLine("Root directory: {0}", Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(dir));
Console.WriteLine("Current directory: {0}", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
```

Comment: i totaly forgot on that, i was concentrated on other ways... bah! Thanks